# Need advice on setting up a wireless bridge, both having wireless PCs, without using a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I wish to setup a wireless bridge between two routers, both of which will have wireless clients; however, I want to do this without using a repeater.  I would prefer not to have the bandwidth halved.

I have a linksys wrt54g router (secondary) and a linksys e2500, simultaneous dusl-band N router (primary). I want to connect them wirelessly on the same subnet, aka wireless bridge, AND connect wireless clients to the secondary router.  dd-wrt says I can use a mode which combines wireless bridging and repeating, a wireless repeater, but this halves the bandwidth for all wireless clients.  Is there anyway to achieve the same result, sans a repeater with two linksys routers?  Or, will I need to buy additional equipment to realize a wirelessly bridged network, with wireless clients connected to both routers, without using a repeater function?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the bandwidth is havled is because the wireless devices are quickly switching between client and AP mode.  If you want the wireless devices to act as both a standard wireless AP and also a client, which is necessary to connect to another AP wirelessly, there is no avoiding this.

If you only care about having one of the wireless devices act as an AP, I do believe somehow dd-wrt allows you to configure things such that basically the unit's wireless will be a client to your second wireless device that should be running in AP mode.

Effectively, the first wireless device's Wifi becomes the "WAN" port and it depends on the other one being an AP for internet connectivity, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and help.  So, without purchasing additional equipment and without using a repeater, perhaps I can set it up as wireless non-bridge; that is, connect the two routers wirelessly, with the second network existing on a different subnet (ap client mode).  In this way, could I then connect wireless PCs to the secondary router AND wireless PCs to the primary router?  Actually, I don't think that will work.  I probably have to settle for a wireless repeater bridge or purchase additional equipment.

Comment: If you are talking to wireless router A, but using Internet access on wireless router B, you have to send every data packet to router A and then router A has to send it to router B. This halves the available bandwidth. The only way to avoid this is to use an additional router to double the available bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you, David.  When you say an additional router to double the available bandwidth, do you mean router A has its own subnet, e.g. 192.168.2.x?  Configuring a second router on its own subnet will preserve bandwidth; is this correct?

Comment: In what I'm talking about, router A would be a wifi client to router B (like any other laptop, phone, or other wifi device), and router B needs to be Internet facing (with likely your dsl/cable modem connected to the WAN).  So there would be no bandwidth loss, but only router B can be the access point.  You would have to connect devices to router A only through its LAN ports.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Thank you very much.  Ahh, I see.  So, in that case, if I want wireless clients to communicate with router A, I'll need to purchase an AP and connect it to a LAN port on router A.  That way, no bandwidth loss and both router A and router B can ultimately communicate with wireless clients.  Thank you for your help.